# ASP.NET select element inside Layout Template

Tags: asp.net

If I add Layout Template element like the following code, I am not able to select element directly.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
        </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Instead, I need to select element like this:

```
String userName = LoginUser.UserName.Text;
```

Actually, what is the use of LayoutTemplate and why does it cause me not able to select element directly?

Comment: in your 'I need to ...' statement, you write that you need to select the element, which to me means the UserName element. but it seems you want the text value of the username, not the UserName element itself. I posted an answer to how you retrieve the text that the user enters in the username and password boxes.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutTemplate helps you designing multiple layouts. 
You can have more than 1 layout.

Answer (score 0):

The LayoutTemplate is only here to customize the appearance of the Login Control. The Login Control encapsulates the inner Control like an Placeholder. Maybe you want to use the [Authenticate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the username and password while verifying the userdata.

Answer (score 0):

Cato, i have a similar question. but i was able to get the username and password text values with this code:

```
string userName = LoginUser.UserName;
string passWord = LoginUser.Password;
```

That 'UserName' and 'Password' property on LoginUser are *string* values, not the elements themselves, which is my problem. I need to get the element because i want to set focus on the username element. But Microsoft seems to have put us between a rock and a hard place, yet again, on this issue.

But it seems to me, that the string values are what you were looking for anyways. So maybe my response answers your question.